# Where is the .NET command line compiler?

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, csc

Where is the .NET command line compiler (csc.exe) located after install?

I'm trying to set up my path to compile C# applications from the command line, but I can't find where csc.exe has been installed.

I'm using .NET 4 and Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the respective `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vXXXX` folder.

Each version of the runtime has its own compiler, which would make 4.0:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
```

Your minor version (the `30319`) may vary.